# UiCollectionView inside UitableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a uicollectionView inside a tableview cell. I am trying to figure out to have unique data source for each collectionview based on the index of the tableViewCell. Here is what I have so far... How do you get each cell to have different collectionview data source?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UILabel *title = (UILabel* )[cell viewWithTag:100];

    title.text = [collection1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The question is there.

Answer (score 0):

This should set you on the right track:

Your data source for your `UITableView` should be a collection of data sources for each cell and hence each `UICollectionView`. So for example, say you want to show some images in each of your `UICollectionViewCells`. In this scenario, the data source for your `UITableView` could be an Array containing Arrays of images (one Array of images for each cell in your `UITableView`).

You will need a custom `UITableViewCell` that exposes a method like "SetDataSourceForCollectionView".

Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of the `UITableView` you can get the data source for the cell by indexing your collection using the `NSIndexPath` parameter. Just pass this value to the `SetDataSourceForCollectionView`method of your `UITableViewCell`.

Your custom `UITableViewCell` now has a datasource it can assign to it's `UICollectionView`.